Save composable as image file with transparent background in Jetpack Compose
I'm building a functionality of sharing part of the screen as an image file. Here is a reference to docs:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/graphics/draw/modifiers#composable-to-bitmap
This works fine, but I need the resulting file to have rounded corners over transparent background. What I've tried:

Clipping with GraphicsLayer. This makes corners rounded, but background is black.
Altering of bitmap, received from GraphicsLayer seems impossible, because it has Config.HARDWARE. I didn't find a way to make it mutable or copy it to another Bitmap. I can't even check the color of the pixels - all these operations result in IllegalStateException.

So, is it possible to make background of the image file transparent somehow?
Here is my code:
@Composable
fun SomeComposable() {
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        val graphicsLayer = rememberGraphicsLayer()
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val radius = 16.dp.toPx(context)

        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .drawWithContent {
                    graphicsLayer.clipWith(radius, this@drawWithContent.size)
                    // call record to capture the content in the graphics layer
                    graphicsLayer.record {
                        // draw the contents of the composable into the graphics layer
                        this@drawWithContent.drawContent()
                    }
                    // draw the graphics layer on the visible canvas
                    drawLayer(graphicsLayer)
                }
                .background(Color.Red)
        ) {
            Button(onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    val bitmap = graphicsLayer.toImageBitmap().asAndroidBitmap()
                    context.shareWithChooser(bitmap)
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "Share")
            }
        }
}

private fun GraphicsLayer.clipWith(radius: Float, size: Size) {
        clip = true
        setOutline(
            Outline.Rounded(
                RoundRect(
                    0f,
                    0f,
                    size.width,
                    size.height,
                    cornerRadius = CornerRadius(radius, radius)
                )
            )
        )
}

suspend fun Context.shareWithChooser(bitmap: Bitmap) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val file = File.createTempFile("IMG_", ".jpg", filesDir)
        val stream = FileOutputStream(file)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
        stream.flush()
        stream.close()

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val imageUri =
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(this@shareWithChooser, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file)
            val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
                type = "image/jpeg"
                flags =
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                data = imageUri

                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
            }
            val chooser = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "")
            startActivity(chooser)
        }
    }
}


Your setup seems to work just fine for me. Here's a screenshot of the result of a test run at 100.dp saved to a PNG and opened in MSPaint: https://i.sstatic.net/rUyVlljk.png. You can see that the background has the checkerboard pattern. Seems like the problem might be with how it's being displayed.

I just realized, you're saving it as a JPEG, which doesn't support transparency.

@Mike M. Wow! I didn't think of the file extension at all. That really did work, thanks a lot! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

No problem! I'm good, though. Nothin' huge. Please feel free to finish this up however you like. Thank you. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!
